# How can i show part of View at first in DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I'm using `DrawerLayout` now. I want to show a part of View in advance like below.

[image]

As you can see, we can see the part of View with `android:layout_gravity="end"`.
If i swipe from right to left, i can see the entire view. 
[image]

The photos above are not real. I made them just to show you.

This below is what i made.
**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/drawerContent"
        layout="@layout/view_drawer_side_content"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**view_drawer_side_content.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/atvDetailMobileSpecDrawerButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="C\nO\nN\nT\nE\nN\nT"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_left_12dp_gray333"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText,SpUsage" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewDetailMobileSpecDetailBorder1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/inDetailMobileDrawerDeviceSpecGuide"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/atvDetailMobileSpecDrawerButton"
        android:background="@color/grayd7" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/inDetailMobileDrawerDeviceSpecGuide"
        layout="@layout/in_device_spec_guide_detail"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/atvDetailMobileSpecDrawerButton"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/viewDetailMobileSpecDetailBorder2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/atvDetailMobileSpecDrawerButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/inDetailMobileDrawerDeviceSpecGuide"
        android:background="@color/grayd7" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But What i want to do are..
**1. How can i show the part of View in advance?** 
**2. I only want to show the entire view when i swipe the content textView area, not the entire right side.**

is it possible?

Comment: After thinking about this further, I was wrong about the touch handling. We actually can do that without forking `DrawerLayout`, by juggling the lock mode, but it's a little tedious: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EXMTiwV9zD2NVA0Gt9j-ekxeCsbdNguC/view?usp=share_link. Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/br7ZV.gif. It might take a bit more work to get that looking and behaving exactly like you want, though, so it still might be easier to look for a library that'll do it out of the box.

Comment: I updated that example to use a `TextView` instead of a drawable, so it's closer to your design. Now it looks more like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d0l6.gif. Just FYI.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I saw the gif that you uploaded. it was what i wanted to make. But in your code, i can't access `findDrawerWithGravity` and `getDrawerViewOffset`.

Comment: Yeah, those are package-private methods in `DrawerLayout`, so that class has to be in `package androidx.drawerlayout.widget`, not in your app's package. If you just change the line at the top of your class file, Android Studio should underline it with a warning, and the hover menu should have a quick fix option to move it for you. It'll simply create the relevant folders under your source directory, and move the file there. We can implement our own versions of those methods if we have to – and therefore move the class to wherever – but I thought this was the simplest way to do a quick demo.